Homebrew DND 5e Spell, review in power, and well... utility
So, I usually design spells without a care in the world for how powerful or weak it might be, since you generally find that out with testing. However, in this particular case it made me wonder, and realize, how hard is to assess this kind of thing when the power, and utility of high level spells seems so varied.
So with that in mind, I ask for a general review, and your general train of thought when judging homebrew.

Malignant Sphere
6th-level illusion
Casting Time: 10 minutes
Range: 60 feet
Components: V, S, M (a dreamcatcher with gold dipped feathers worth at least 200 gp, which the spell consumes)
Duration: Until dispelled
You create a small illusory yellow orb that floats five feet above the ground in an unoccupied space within range. The orb sheds 5 feet of dim light, cannot be moved, and lasts until dispelled.
When a creature first sees the orb, it must make a Charisma saving throw. On a failed save, their minds are flooded by vivid visions of their worse nightmares, taking 8d10 psychic damage and becoming frightened of the orb for 1 minute. On a successful save, it takes half as much damage and isn't frightened by this spell.
Additionally, a creature that failed the save must make another saving throw at the end of their next long rest. On a failed save, their minds are tormented once again by the nightmarish visages, taking 4d10 psychic damage, and gaining no benefits from the long rest.
A creature that succeeds the initial Charisma saving throws is immune to the effects of this spell for the next 24 hours.
At Higher Levels. When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 7th level or higher, the damage from the initial Charisma saving throw increases by 2d10 for each slot level above 6th, and the damage at the end of each long rest increases by 1d10 for each slot level above 6th.

That's a great way to murder hobo a town.

The spell description both says "When a creature first sees the orb" and that creatures succeeding the save are immune for 24 hours. Is it intended that the spell works only once per creature or once per day per creature (and potentially multiple times if the save is failed)?

What happens if someone sees multiple Spheres at once? Say I put 10 of them in my wizard tower behind a curtain, wait for the party to arrive and then drop the curtain? Do they start taking Charisma saving throws until they succeed once (making them immune to the Spell in general, not just that particular casting of the spell?) or they've failed 10 times (and taken 80d10 damage)?

Using a Wisdom saving throw rather than a Charisma saving throw would be both more thematically appropriate (since Charisma saves are usually reserved for physical changes to the world) and it would meaningfully decrease the power of the spell, since Wisdom saving throws are more commonly resisted.

I think this is too strong for 6th and needs more clarifying info to be used
Right now, this spell seems like a combination of the Dream spell (5th level) and a toned down version of the antipathy effect from the Antipathy/Sympathy spell (8th level). There's also comparisons to be made to warding spells like Hallow, Guards and Wards, Forbiddance, and Symbol.
I'm going to focus on the utility of this spell first and let that weave in discussions on its power.

When a creature first sees the orb, it must make a Charisma saving throw.

I'm trying to understand what the threshold is for seeing the orb. It seems like maybe it should be creatures within 60', but there is no information in the spell's description to clarify that. Additionally, I note that there are no exemption criteria, meaning you and your allies are just as subject to being affected by this spell as anyone else. As written, I'm not clear how a caster creates this effect and avoids having to save against it.
An additional issue with how this spell is written is that if seems like you could cast this in a tall tower of a building and potentially subject an entire city's population to its effect if wide-scale murder was a goal of the caster.
The lack of range makes me feel like this spell is overpowered. If the intent is that it's creatures who see it and are within 60', it's a bit better, but again I'm unclear how the caster uses this spell without subjecting themselves to the effect.

Duration: Until dispelled

I'm assuming this duration was chosen because the expensive material component is consumed with the casting, similar to spells like Magic Mouth or Glyph of Warding. There are other spells as well to compare against like Hallow, Guards and Wards, and Forbiddance all of which can be made permanent either via a longer casting time, multiple castings, or more costly components; however, only Forbiddance is able to cause direct damage to enemies and even then they have to be extraplanar creatures.
I don't necessarily have an issue with the spell being made permanent, but it may be more in-line with prior practice to require that the effect is only made permanent after casting it every day for a month or something.

6-th level illusion

One concern I do have, though, is that this works on everything. The nearest comparable effect I could find for this spell was the Symbol spell, which is 7th level. In a way, this does more than that spell because it deals both damage and the frightened condition, but in a way it also does less because a successful save removes the need for further saves. Symbol is just 10 minutes of DO NOT ENTER.
I'm just going off of feel and saying that the combination of proposed effects including messing with character's long rest benefits, warrants setting this at 7th level.

To summarize:

Clarify the effective range. 60' is probably appropriate.
Include some ability by the caster to designate ineligible targets.
Make the duration 24 hours, but allow the caster to make it permanent by recasting on the same location for 30 days, upon the 30th day the costly components are consumed.
Make it a 7th level spell.
Clarify if creatures that failed the initial save can avoid the 2nd save if someone successfully dispels the effect on them. Or maybe a good spot to add a scenario for Remove Curse. This creates an avenue for characters to react and avoid a nasty secondary effect.


Excellent points, and I agree with about everything. Gotta say tho, quite the oversight in my part, had completely forgotten about the range already, but the fact that the caster is going to be affected made me laugh a little.

In my conceptualization of the spell, I wanted a defensive yet, dangerous spell. So I wanted the very party to have to be careful of this spell. Not giving it a range limit made it go to a different direction. Thanks for the great answer, will definitely take your points to paper.

Spell balance is indeed pretty ballpark-y, but I would say this is too strong for a 6th-level spell. Here's my thought process:
AOE
This spell has a technically infinite AOE, i.e. it could easily wipe out an entire city; that's probably a bit strong for a level 6 spell. I would add some sort of range stipulation (30 feet?) on provoking the orb's effects in addition to having to see it. Maybe even a limit on how many creatures it can affect.
Duration
The fact that it has an unlimited duration is also quite powerful. guards and wards only lasts for 24 hours, and is infinitely less lethal as a deterrent/defense. Your spell should probably last no longer than 24 hours considering how lethal it is. Maybe it becomes permanent when cast at 9th level?
Cost
If it were to remain as-is, 200gp is far too low a barrier to entry. A permanent torch costs 50gp (via continual flame); a permanent murder-orb should probably cost significantly more.

I see, fair points through, and through. As to the cost and the duration, I was referring to the spell Symbol in the making. A 7th level spell, that has an "until dispelled" duration and a cost of 1,000 gp. The range is definitely an oversight, tho.
Thanks for the answer, btw!

@Peixoto while Symbol lasts until dispelled or triggered ("…for 10 minutes, after which time the spell ends."), the Malignant Sphere could be triggered again and again.

This idea is fundamentally unbalanced.  A savvy PC might choose to spend 1000 gold to make 5 of them.  With each of them doing 8d10, there's not much that will survive looking at them and so whatever they're defending becomes impregnable.
Heck, even if the players aren't immune, they can take the damage from the spheres one at a time because they know they're there (casting healing spells, in between) and then lead an enemy army into the spheres and slaughter them all.

Basically a permanent reusable minefield... Or should I call it a mindfield?

Worse--make a bunch of them, put them behind a barrier.  Drop the barrier when the enemy shows up.
